# Find Divisor and Dividend from Remainder

Tags: divisibility

I am developing some software to "Mutate" inline constants in source code to make them hard to read (eg. Obfuscation) and need a way to determine two values that when divided by each other gets a predetermined remainder.

I have read up on the Remainder theorem but am finding it difficult to wrap my head around exactly what I need to implement/determine.

Basically I need a way to do the following:

Original:

```
x = 12
```

Mutated:

```
x = 1561312 % 13
```

Of course the dividend and the divisor will be much larger (I'm thinking of values like `1825141394`). I considered brute forcing, but I thought I might ask around math exchange if you knew a formula or algorithm that would do what I wanted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work backwards. Given your remainder $r$ ($12$ in the example), make a "random" choice of $q$ and $m$, with $m\gt r$, and calculate $x=qm +r$. Then use $x\,\%\, m$.

Comment: Does $x$ have to be positive?

Comment: You can use negative $q$ if you want, giving negative $x$.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Works now! Was getting some weird negatives but that was due to some integer overflows (`int.MaxValue * int.MaxValue` is never good ;)). Thanks heaps again!

Comment: You are welcome. I am afraid I can give no programming advice, the last serious programming I did (a long time ago) was in Assembler.